# Where are the NHibernate/Hibernate HQL and ICriteria query examples?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, orm, hql, icriteria

I'm still quite new to NHibernate and most of it I'm getting to grips with.  One area that I'm really lacking a proper understanding of though is querying (at least when it comes to anything reasonably complex).

I learn best by example, but I feel that I haven't really been able to find all that many in depth querying examples on the web.  There are there are quite a few of course - but there are many different techniques and approaches, and most of the examples seem to gloss over the details.

(For instance in the official nhibernate documentation, the [ICriteria explanation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-criteria) comprises 4 sentences!)

Maybe I just haven't looked well enough? ;)  **Does anyone know of any good resources (on the web) with lots of query examples? (Both HQL and ICriteria prefferably).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StackOverflow. I'm serious - go into `Hibernate` and `NHibernate` tags and search for `Criteria` and / or `HQL`. There are tons of questions / answers. I know because I wrote a lot of them :-)

NHibernate manual sections on [HQL](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) and [Criteria](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) have quite a few examples as well.

Finally, you can always post a question if you're having trouble with something. When / if you do, be aware that posting appropriate mappings / classes / tables makes it a lot easier to understand / answer any question related to Hibernate queries.

Comment: Hah, yeah that might be my best bet :)